# django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration ... is applied before its dependency

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I get this exception:

```
myproject@aptguettler:~$ manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myproject/src/djangotools/djangotools/bin/manage.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/myproject/src/djangotools/djangotools/bin/manage.py", line 29, in main
    execute_from_command_line()
  File "/home/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 86, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/myproject/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 292, in check_consistent_history
    connection.alias,
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration myapp.0029_bar is applied before its dependency myapp.0005_foo_squashed_0028_dynamic_year on database 'default'.
```

My migrations:

```
                   name                    
-------------------------------------------
 0001_initial
 0002_...
 0003_...
 0004_...
 0005_foo
 0006_...
 0007_...
...
 0028_dynamic_year
 0029_bar
 0030_...
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason with the help of a team mate.

He did this:

1. squashed migrations
2. Production deployment and makemigrations
3. Deleted the squashed python files in the migration directory

I updated the git repo in my (old) develoment system. Then `make migrations` raised above exception.

Django can't solve this, since some migrations were applied and some not and the old squashed migration files are not available any more.

I took the most simple solution: I dropped my development database and created it from scratch.